# Does the negative interrogative "Haven't you noticed that ..." correspond to the affirmative "Tu remarqueras que ..." in French?

Tags: temps-grammatical

> **Tu remarqueras** qu'il ne nous a même pas donné son nom. C'est normal d'être prudent.

I just heard my girlfriend say this, and I found the use of the future tense "remarqueras" interesting. What she meant was "**Haven't you noticed** that he ... **?**" or in her native tongue "**Ты не заметил**, что он ... **?**".

In both English and Russian, the idea is phrased with a negative interrogative sentence, not an affirmative one, and the tense used is essentially the past, not the future.

Is it more common to use the affirmative construction and the future tense "Tu remarqueras que ..." in French to express this idea? And are there some other similar phrasings?

Answer (score 4):

> Tu remarqueras qu'il ne nous a même pas donné son nom.

is formal French.

In casual conversations, the negative form would be common:

> T'as pas remarqué qu'il nous a même pas donné son nom ?
>
> T'as pas vu qu'il nous a même pas...

but the positive one seems equally possible, still using the *passé composé* :

> T'as remarqué qu'il nous a même pas donné son nom.

This last sentence can be either an affirmative or an interrogative.

In a formal conversation, the interrogative form is possible too:

> N'as-tu pas remarqué qu'il ne nous a même pas donné son nom ?

Answer (score 1):

"Vous/Tu remarqueras que…" is a construction that is not an understatement for a question and should therefore  not be translated in English by means of a question. 
It is an assertion aiming at imparting to the interlocutor the matter of factness as to our understanding that he/she can't but **notice or have noticed** what is in question : "it's evident, he/she will see it, notice it, if that hasn't been done yet, by thinking about the situation he/she will deduce it and be able to make a remark". Therefore, more proper is a translation by a sentence in the affirmative, for instance as shown below;

- You can't but notice that he didn't even tell us his name.  *or*
- You must have noticed that he didn't even tell us his name.